# multiple file validation using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to upload multiple files via

```
<input type="file" id="uploadFiles" multiple onchange="checkFileUploadExt(this);"/>
```

using javascript

```
function checkFileUploadExt(fieldObj)
{
    var control = document.getElementById("uploadFiles");
    var filelength = control.files.length;
    var FileName = fieldObj.value;
    var FileExt = FileName.substr(FileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);       
    if ((FileExt.toUpperCase() != "PDF"))
        if ((FileExt !== "pdf") || (FileExt !== "PDF"))
        {
            var error = "File type : " + FileExt + "\n\n";
            error += "Please make sure your file is in pdf  format .\n\n";
            alert(error);
            fieldObj.value = '';
            return false;
        }  

    return true;
}
```

but here

> multiple pdf files->success
>
> single other files(.txt,.doc etc)->success
>
> pdf+(txt or doc)-> fail

my need is only pdf files can accept when multiple selection.
and also it shows errors in files.length on Interner Explorer
how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```js
function checkFileUploadExt(fieldObj) {
  var control = document.getElementById("uploadFiles");
  var filelength = control.files.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < control.files.length; i++) {
    var file = control.files[i];
    var FileName = file.name;
    var FileExt = FileName.substr(FileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    if ((FileExt.toUpperCase() != "PDF")) {
      var error = "File type : " + FileExt + "\n\n";
      error += "Please make sure your file is in pdf  format .\n\n";
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="uploadFiles" multiple onchange="checkFileUploadExt(this);" />
```

Comment: pdf+doc->success , doc+pdf-> fails

Comment: My answer just checks if the selected files format is correct or not and logs the wrong ones

Comment: here i have to select single or multiple pdf files only.but here when i select two files exaple a doc and pdf it fails but pdf and doc it become success(i mean the selection order).

Comment: with my code, there is no difference with the order

Comment: just run in code snippet in the order (1).docx (2).pdf [select both with control tab]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `accept` filter instead.

Here's a **demo**:

```html
<input name="file1" type="file" accept="application/pdf" multiple />
```

PS: It doesnt work in Firefox.

---

**Alternate and Promising solution:**

```js
document.getElementById("uploadFiles").onchange = function(){  // on selecting file(s)
    for(var file in this.files){ // loop over all files
        if(isNaN(file) === false){  // if it is actually a file and not any other property
            if(this.files[file].type !== "application/pdf"){ // if NOT PDF!!
                alert('Please select PDF files only.');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    alert('Yay!! All selected files are in PDF format.');
    return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="uploadFiles" multiple accept="application/pdf" />
```

PS: This works in Firefox too!